# How to extract fastest and slowest values from separate Excel files per year, considering trial count conditions, and combine results using Python?

Tags: python, excel, sorting, concatenation

I am working with historical data related to some sports trial for different athletes per year. The data is in excel format and we have one excel file per year that stores the trail data for different athletes where each sheet contains data for one athlete. For example, this is sort of what the data looks like:

```
Sheet 1: 
SheetName: 14056
Data: 
Candidate   Trial ID    Performance
14056   11001   194.129
14056   11002   92.947
14056   11003   262.029
Sheet 2: 
SheetName: 14057
Data: 
Candidate   Trial ID    Performance
14057   12001   22.36
14057   12002   145.21
14057   12003   78.9
14057   12004   69.23
```

And the list goes on, where we have 100s of sheets with similar data.

From these data, I want to get the fastest and slowest trail performance of each athlete in a year. So, I want to read all these excel sheets, process the data so that I have the fastest and slowest time of each athlete, combine all these into a single sheet and save as a separate excel. However, I have the following condition:

If a sheet has four or more trial data, then I need to get two fastest and two slowest performances of each athlete. If there are less than four trials, I need to get only one fastest and slowest per athlete.

I have written the following function in python that gets the input data and processes it. But right now, I am getting two fastest and two slowest times for each athlete regardless of the condition. For example, if I have only two trail data in the input file, this function saves both trials as two slowest and two fastest.

I have minimum experience with python, so any help will be highly appreciated.

```
def process_excel_file(input_data):
    logger.info(f"Processing file: {input_data}")
    xlsx = pd.ExcelFile(input_data)
    fastest_data = []
    slowest_data = []

    for sheet in xlsx.sheet_names:
        df = pd.read_excel(input_data, sheet_name=sheet)
        if not df.empty:
            df["Performance"] = pd.to_numeric(df["Performance"], errors="coerce")
            df.dropna(subset=["Performance"], inplace=True)
            df = df.sort_values(by="Performance")

            fastest_data.append(df.nsmallest(2, "Performance"))
            slowest_data.append(df.nlargest(2, "Performance"))

    fastest = pd.concat(fastest_data)
    slowest = pd.concat(slowest_data)

    fastest["Category"] = "Fastest Trial"
    slowest["Category"] = "Slowest Trial"
    combined_data = pd.concat([fastest, slowest])
    combined_data.sort_values(by="Candidate", inplace=True)

    return combined_data
```

Comment: You're not counting the number of rows in each sheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did the following to solve it.

```
def process_excel_file(input_data):
    logger.info(f"Processing file: {input_data}")
    xlsx = pd.ExcelFile(input_data)
    fastest = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Candidate", "Trial ID", "Performance"])
    slowest = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Candidate", "Trial ID", "Performance"])
    for sheet in xlsx.sheet_names:
        df = pd.read_excel(input_data, sheet_name=sheet)
        if not df.empty:
            df["Performance"] = pd.to_numeric(df["Performance"], errors="coerce")
            df.dropna(subset=["Performance"], inplace=True)
            df = df.sort_values(by="Performance")
            num_trials = len(df)
            num_res = 2 if num_trials >= 4 else 1
            fastest_performances = df.nsmallest(num_res, "Performance")
            slowest_performances = df.nlargest(num_res, "Performance")

            if num_trials == 1:
                fastest = pd.concat([fastest, df[["Candidate", "Trial ID", "Performance"]]])
            else:
                fastest = pd.concat([fastest, fastest_performances[["Candidate", "Trial ID", "Performance"]]])
                slowest = pd.concat([slowest, slowest_performances[["Candidate", "Trial ID", "Performance"]]])

    fastest["Category"] = "Fastest Trial"
    slowest["Category"] = "Slowest Trial"
    combined_data = pd.concat([fastest, slowest])
    combined_data.sort_values(by="Candidate", inplace=True)

    return combined_data
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to take account of the number of rows in each sheet. The middle part of your code becomes:

```
df = df.sort_values(by="Performance")
n = 2 if df.shape[0] >= 4 else 1
fastest_data.append(df.nsmallest(n, "Performance"))
slowest_data.append(df.nlargest(n, "Performance"))
```